# Assembly language registers changes

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system

I am running assembly language 64bit code on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    ;display on screen
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, length
    syscall

    ;exit gracefuly
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 11
    syscall

section .data
    message: db 'Hello world!',0xa
    length: equ $-message
```

But when i disasseble it using gdb, it is dumping eax,edi,edx,eax and edi register insted of rax,rdi,rdx,rax and rdi register respectively...

```
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x00000000004000b0 <+0>:     mov    eax,0x1
   0x00000000004000b5 <+5>:     mov    edi,0x1
   0x00000000004000ba <+10>:    movabs rsi,0x6000d8
   0x00000000004000c4 <+20>:    mov    edx,0xd
   0x00000000004000c9 <+25>:    syscall 
   0x00000000004000cb <+27>:    mov    eax,0x3c
   0x00000000004000d0 <+32>:    mov    edi,0xb
   0x00000000004000d5 <+37>:    syscall 
End of assembler dump.
```

Why this is happening ?

Comment: The assembler optimized it for you, since 32 bit operations get zero extended to 64 bit, so you actually get what you asked for (remember that the `e*` registers are the low 32 bits of the `r*`).

Comment: Which assembler is this ?

Comment: Linux 64bit assembly